# How do "Temporary ASP.NET Files" get created (and how to prevent duplicates)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an issue where a dll shown twice in the Modules debug window for my WCF service (hosted by an IIS Project).

They are both loaded from my "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folders.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\d9bf3211\b2544e2b\assembly\dl3\4cfa5823\28f464b9_9a03cd01\InversionOfControl.DLL
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\d9bf3211\b2544e2b\assembly\dl3\4cfa5823\2457a584_9803cd01\InversionOfControl.dll
```

The paths are almost exactly the same, but the folder name that holds the dll is different.

So here are my questions:

1. What is "Temporary ASP.NET Files" for?
2. Why not just reference the dll that is in my build folder.
3. **How could I have gotten two?**
4. **How can I prevent it from happening again?**
5. If I just delete them will this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743782/the-type-inversionofcontrol-ioc-exists-in-both-inversionofcontrol-dll-and-i) be "fixed"?

The ones in bold are the answers I am most interested in.

Comment: Here are some explanations ...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can feel free to delete anything below `Temporary ASP.NET Files`. All of the contents will be generated again (albeit with an initial performance penalty).

Also note that it is easier to use explorer to do this if you kill IIS temporarily. (`iisreset /stop`, delete the files, `iisreset /start`).

Answer (score 1):

All you need to know different approaches for compiling your code by asp.net.

Do pre compile your code in order to avoid compiling and storing compiled files in temporary folders.

Hope this article will give you better answer for your questions. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/precompiling-your-website-vb

Comment: I do not precompile.  I just do a "Rebuild All" in Visual Studio and then run the project.  Then I am getting errors from having two of these dlls. (See here for the errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743782/the-type-inversionofcontrol-ioc-exists-in-both-inversionofcontrol-dll-and-i)

Comment: Well .net delete temp files at time of building, there may be possibility due to some reason if failed to delete some files. If these files continuously generate error, then try to manually delete it and see result.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting them has no negative impact to your system.

.Net will just keep creating them slowly but surely filling up the drive.  On dev machines, there are a lot of them.   On servers... well, you shouldn't be deploying code to the server that requires compilation anyway.

Regarding whether it will fix your problem... maybe.  Go for it.